# Android - How to force spinner dropdown to open right-aligned

Tags: android, android-spinner

On an app that I am working on, I have a small spinner on the right hand side of the screen.

The problem is that on some devices the spinner dropdown opens right-aligned, while on others the spinner dropdown opens left-aligned, with the text coming off the screen.

I would like to know, is there a way to force the spinner dropdown to open right-aligned on all devices to prevent the text from coming off the screen?

EDIT: Here is the XML for the Spinner:

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/reportList"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question, and what properties have you used in your XML File

Comment: Basically, I would like right side of my dropdown to line up with the right side of my spinner when opened on all devices.  Unfortunately on some devices they are lining up on their left sides, causing text to go off screen.

Answer (score 0):

For resizing the Spinner's window [this solution](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55063/limitar-altura-de-un-spinner-desde-layout/55080#55080)  was propposed in a different question.

The question was asked in Spanish but see the answer of Jorgesys that uses reflection. Perhaps it puts you on the right path.

Comment: Okay, for KitKat and above, it looks like I can use reflection and call the `setDropDownGravity` method.  However, how would I manually set the gravity for devices running Jelly Bean or below?

Comment: Have you tried using  android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow insttead of android.widget.ListPopupWindow?

Comment: Note aside, just for you to evaluate how much back compatibility you need to maintain, Under Api 16 there are no working devices left, and Api 16 to 19 (Jelly Bean) represents a 10% of de working devices. You can check it here: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: My minimum is API 16.

Comment: BTW, `setDropDownGravity` doesn't seem to do anything on older devices.  Also, setting the offset manually doesn't seem to do anything either.

Comment: Using the support library, I get the error `android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow`.

Comment: The idea is to use the support version instead of the widget, not cast it.